# Running Sqlite in a docker container

Tags: docker, sqlite, entity-framework, .net-core, webapi

I have a small application that I want to containerize in .Net5.0. It works well outside docker but if added `RUN dotnet ef database update` to my docker file, it gives a build error. I don't know if I placed it in a wrong place or it doesn't work that way.

Also will `COPY --from=publish /app/publish/tomix.db .` copy the new database file correctly?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
RUN dotnet ef database update
RUN dotnet restore "API/API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/tomix.db .
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

**UPDATE** This is the error after running `dotnet build -t tomix .`
[image: dotnet ef database update error]

Comment: What's the build error?

Comment: I am unsure why you would want to run `dotnet ef database update` in your docker file? Updating the database should happen when the application runs not when the image is build?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the dotnet ef tool is no longer part of the .NET SDK, and needs to be explicitly installed. I.e., before attempting to `RUN dotnet ef database update` you must `RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-ef`

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik however, the error doesn't go away.